# Unity 2d Camera Scale to Screen Size

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking to scale a orthographic camera in unity 2d to screen size.

When you edit your game you orient the camera in a way you want it to be, view all your objects etc.

But then when you maximise it your camera zooms out showing maybe other things you don't want to show

Images for example

[Edit Mode View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWxlV.png)

[Maximised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWM5D.png)

Thank you if you can answer my question

Best Regards

Dawid

Comment: Check out [`this`](https://answers.unity.com/questions/526841/changing-ortho-cam-size-according-to-resolution.html) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the following component to your camera. Make sure to set the target aspect ratio in the inspector (16/9 for example).

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class ViewportScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera _camera;

    [Tooltip("Set the target aspect ratio.")]
    [SerializeField] private float _targetAspectRatio;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        if (Application.isPlaying)
            ScaleViewport();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (_camera)
            ScaleViewport();
#endif
    }

    private void ScaleViewport()
    {
        // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
        var windowaspect = Screen.width / (float) Screen.height;

        // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
        var scaleheight = windowaspect / _targetAspectRatio;

        // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
        if (scaleheight < 1)
        {
            var rect = _camera.rect;

            rect.width = 1;
            rect.height = scaleheight;
            rect.x = 0;
            rect.y = (1 - scaleheight) / 2;

            _camera.rect = rect;
        }
        else // add pillarbox
        {
            var scalewidth = 1 / scaleheight;

            var rect = _camera.rect;

            rect.width = scalewidth;
            rect.height = 1;
            rect.x = (1 - scalewidth) / 2;
            rect.y = 0;

            _camera.rect = rect;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: very helpful, I needed a bit more flexibility for my project so expanded on your code (I posted it as answer because of character limits in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on @sean-carey 's very useful answer.

I modified his code in order to add a min and max aspect ratio, so the viewport will be full screen in between those two aspects, and will pillarbox when < min and letterbox when > max

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class ViewportController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera _camera;

    [Tooltip("Set the target aspect ratio.")]
    [SerializeField] private float _minAspectRatio;
    [SerializeField] private float _maxAspectRatio;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

        if (Application.isPlaying)
            ScaleViewport();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (_camera)
            ScaleViewport();
#endif
    }

    private void ScaleViewport()
    {
        // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
        var windowaspect = Screen.width / (float) Screen.height;

        // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
        var letterboxRatio = windowaspect / _minAspectRatio;
        var pillarboxRatio = _maxAspectRatio / windowaspect;

        // if max height is less than current height, add letterbox
        if (letterboxRatio < 1)
        {
            SetRect(1, letterboxRatio, 0, (1-letterboxRatio)/2);
        }
        // if min height is more than current height, add pillarbox
        else if (pillarboxRatio < 1)
        {
            SetRect(pillarboxRatio, 1, (1-pillarboxRatio)/2, 0);
        }
        // full screen
        else
        {
            SetRect(1, 1, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void SetRect(float w, float h, float x, float y)
    {
        var rect = _camera.rect;

        rect.width = w;
        rect.height = h;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;

        _camera.rect = rect;
    }
}
```